# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FormBuilder.build/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.build/Script-7DE99E1E2A5EB7DB53B88815.sh
    cd /Users/bunny/Desktop/FormBuilder-ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FormBuilder.build/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.build/Script-7DE99E1E2A5EB7DB53B88815.sh

mkdir -p /Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Eureka/Eureka.framework" "/Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Eureka.framework/
Eureka.framework/Eureka
Eureka.framework/Info.plist
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/back-chevron@1x.png
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/back-chevron@2x.png
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/back-chevron@3x.png
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/forward-chevron@1x.png
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/forward-chevron@2x.png
Eureka.framework/Eureka.bundle/forward-chevron@3x.png

sent 3134729 bytes  received 208 bytes  6269874.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3133658  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: zxchow@gmail.com (Z8V4SGV3N5)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign E5132F7DAA611BFC6240AB5F5DB98D7464333FB0  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework'
/Users/bunny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormBuilder-atpgbplzxprmnbczaxqwihnjiknk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FormBuilder.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

This happened after I pod install, but it doesn't affect simulator. I've try to clean and build once, and delete all the "Derived Data" and rebuild again, It kept showing this error. I have totally no idea with it.

Comment: For installing app into iPhone, You should add proper signed certificate.

Comment: Have you specified the correct code signing for the Eureka framework?

Comment: May I know where to add it? Coz' previously I could run it for a month, I didn't did much configuration, I just add an account and it worked.

Comment: Are you using automatic code signing?